# count the number of calls of a clause

Tags: recursion, count, prolog, clause

I have  a clause like following:

```
lock_open:-
        conditional_combination(X),
        equal(X,[8,6,5,3,6,9]),!,
        print(X).
```

this clause succeed. But I want to know how many times conditional_combination() is called before `equal(X,[8,6,5,3,6,9])` is become true. the program is to generate a permutation by following some rules. And I need to how many permutation is need to generate to get a particular value like 865369.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you actually want is something slightly different: You want to count the number of answers (so far) of a goal.

The following predicate [`call_nth(Goal_0, Nth)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/call_nth) succeeds like `call(Goal_0)` but has an additional argument which indicates that the answer found is the n-th answer. This definition is highly specific to SWI or YAP. Do **not** use things like `nb_setarg/3` in your general programs, but use them for well encapsulated cases as this one. Even within
those two systems, the precise meaning of these constructs is not well defined for the general case. [Here is a definition for SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/sicstus-prolog/call_nth.pl). Update: use `unsigned_64` in newer versions instead of `unsigned_32`.

```
call_nth(Goal_0, Nth) :-
   nonvar(Nth),
   !,
   Nth \== 0,
   \+arg(Nth,+ 1,2), % produces all expected errors
   State = count(0,_), % note the extra argument which remains a variable
   Goal_0,
   arg(1, State, C1),
   C2 is C1+1,
   (  Nth == C2
   -> !
   ;  nb_setarg(1, State, C2),
      fail
   ).
call_nth(Goal_0, Nth) :-
   State = count(0,_), % note the extra argument which remains a variable
   Goal_0,
   arg(1, State, C1),
   C2 is C1+1,
   nb_setarg(1, State, C2),
   Nth = C2.
```

A more robust abstraction is provided by Eclipse:

```
call_nth(Goal_0, Nth) :-
   shelf_create(counter(0), CounterRef),
   call(Goal_0),
   shelf_inc(CounterRef, 1),
   shelf_get(CounterRef, 1, Nth).
```

```
?- call_nth(between(1,5,I),Nth).
   I = Nth, Nth = 1
;  I = Nth, Nth = 2
;  I = Nth, Nth = 3
;  I = Nth, Nth = 4
;  I = Nth, Nth = 5.
```

So simply wrap it around:

```
lock_open :-
   call_nth(conditional_combination(X), Nth),
   X = [8,6,5,3,6,9],
   !,
   ....
```

Comment: I see a way to do an **aggregator** O(N) in time **and** space using such primitive. Thanks!

Comment: Have to rethink the limit/2 and offset/2 implementation, maybe the more primitive and universal predicate would be call_nth/2.

Comment: I did not realize that a goal can be called like that (the third line of the `call_nth/2` listing). I thought one always needs `call(Goal)`, but obviously, just `Goal` is enough!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SWI prolog you can use `nb_getval/2` and `nb_setval/2` to achieve what you want:

```
lock_open:- 
  nb_setval(ctr, 0),  % Initialize counter
  conditional_combination(X), 
  nb_inc(ctr),  % Increment Counter
  equal(X,[8,6,5,3,6,9]),
  % Here you can access counter value with nb_getval(ctr, Value)
  !, 
  print(X).

nb_inc(Key):-
  nb_getval(Key, Old),
  succ(Old, New),
  nb_setval(Key, New).
```

Other prologs have other means to do the same, look for global variables in your prolog implementation. In this snippet I used the term `ctr` to hold the current goal counter. You can use any term there that is not used in your program.

Comment: A call to `nb_setval/2` within `conditional_combination/1` would affect the result. A name like `ctr` might be used for some other counting...

Comment: @false: true, OP should use any term not used in his program.

Comment: The point was that you cannot guarantee that without inspecting your entire program.

Comment: You are right, but if you take that position then you would never use assert/call/retract or in fact anything with global effect. In fact just, like in any language, if you use anything global you have to be cautious...

Comment: I disagree: Updating a knowledge base needs something like assert/retract.  And there are ways to prevent that multiple uses of a global are possible. Take as an example `findall/3` using asserta/retract.  You cannot nest such calls, nor can you have two calls at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

While working on a module "micro", I recently invented pivots. They are inspired by the thread / pipe pattern to pass around data. A pivot is a bounded queue of maximum length one, the pivot_put/1 does a copy of the given term as well. But for performance reasons they don't use a synchronized and are non-blocking.

In as far they are very similar to nb_setarg/3, except that they don't destruct a Prolog term, but instead they update a Java data structure. As a result they are little bit safer than the non-logical term operations. Also they don't need some call_cleanup/3, since they are Java garbage collected.

In as far they are more similar than nb_setarg/3, than using some explicit allocate and dealloccate of structures. So for example a solution for SICStus Prolog could be:

```
call_nth(Goal_0, Nth) :-
   new(unsigned_32, Counter),
   call_cleanup(call_nth1(Goal_0, Counter, Nth),
           dispose(Counter)).

call_nth1(Goal_0, Counter, Nth) :-
   call(Goal_0),
   get_contents(Counter, contents, Count0),
   Count1 is Count0+1,
   put_contents(Counter, contents, Count1),
   Nth = Count1.
```

With pivots, there is even no 32-bit limitation, and we can directly do:

```
call_nth(G, C) :-
   pivot_new(P),
   pivot_put(P, 0),
   call(G),
   pivot_take(P, M),
   N is M+1,
   pivot_put(P, N),
   C = N.
```