# Using bagof/3 only for the side effect

Tags: prolog

Solving a very simple exercise in Prolog: print all numbers from 1 to 100, but instead of the number, print 'Fuzz' if number is a multiple of 3, 'Buzz' if multiple of 5, and 'FizzBuzz' if both.

I ended up doing the following:

```
fizzbuzz :- forall( between(1, 100, X), fizzbuzz(X) ).
fizzbuzz(X) :- ( write_fb(X) ; write_n(X) ), nl.

write_fb(X) :- bagof(_, fb(X), _).
fb(X) :- X rem 3 =:= 0, write('Fizz').
fb(X) :- X rem 5 =:= 0, write('Buzz').

write_n(X) :- write(X).
```

but isn't there any predicate or a control structure that would avoid using bagof/3 only for its side effect? (I am always a bit unsure with using predicates only for the side effects).

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the existing answers, I would like to show a more **relational** solution that I hope illustrates some unique benefits of applying a *declarative* programming paradigm such as logic programming to this question.

First, let us recapitulate the task:

> print all numbers from 1 to 100, but instead of the number, print...
>
> - 'Fuzz' if number is a multiple of 3
> - 'Buzz' if multiple of 5
> - and 'FizzBuzz' if both.

The tacit assumption, I presume, is that the numbers are limited to **integers**.

For simplicity, let us first restrict ourselves to a *single* integer, and let us describe the **relation** between such integer and the required output.

The three cases mentioned above can be quite directly translated to Prolog, using your Prolog ystem's **CLP(FD) constraints** for declarative integer arithmetic:

```
integer_output(N, 'Fuzz')     :- N #= 3*_.
integer_output(N, 'Buzz')     :- N #= 5*_.
integer_output(N, 'FizzBuzz') :- N #= 3*_, N #= 5*_.
```

That's not all though, because this yields for example:

```
?- integer_output(4, N).
false.
```

Hence, we need one more case, which we can for example formulate as:

```
integer_output(N, N)          :- N mod 3 #\= 0, N mod 5 #\= 0.
```

This simply states that in the event that none of the other cases applies, we output the number *as is*. The resulting relation is very general. For example, we can use it for **concrete** integers:

```
?- integer_output(1, O).
O = 1.

?- integer_output(3, O).
O = 'Fuzz' ;
false.
```

*And* we can also use it to write **unit tests**, for example:

```
?- integer_output(5, 'Buzz').
true .
```

Here, the intended output is *already specified*, and we can use *the same* relation to ask *whether* the output will be as required. That's a quite nice property of relations, and would not be so easy if we only wrote the output on the system terminal instead of making it explicit as a predicate argument as we did above.

But there's even more! We can also use *the same* relation in the *other* direction, where we ask for example: "*Which* integers result in the output `Buzz`?" Here it is:

```
?- integer_output(I, 'Buzz').
5*_680#=I.
```

That's a massive **generalization** of the earlier test case, and can serve as an additional assurance that we have covered all cases. In fact, we can even generalize this further, resulting in the **most general query** which asks how answers look like *in general*:

```
?- integer_output(I, O).
O = 'Fuzz',
3*_742#=I ;
O = 'Buzz',
5*_742#=I ;
O = 'FizzBuzz',
5*_1014#=I,
3*_1038#=I.
```

Let us reason more about the output. Obviously, we expect that the output is *uniquely determined* for each possible integer, right? Let us **ask Prolog** whether this is so, by asking for **counterexamples** of this property:

```
?- dif(O1, O2),
   integer_output(I, O1),
   integer_output(I, O2).
O1 = 'Fuzz',
O2 = 'Buzz',
5*_1046#=I,
3*_1070#=I ;
O1 = 'Fuzz',
O2 = 'FizzBuzz',
5*_1318#=I,
3*_1342#=I,
3*_1366#=I .
```

Now that doesn't look good : From the above, we already suspect that there *may* be cases of the *same* integer `I` yielding two *different*, equally justifiable, outputs `O1` and `O2`.

And in fact, here's a *concrete* integer where this problem arises:

```
?- integer_output(15, O).
O = 'Fuzz' ;
O = 'Buzz' ;
O = 'FizzBuzz' ;
false.
```

So, it turns out, that the output is *not* uniquely determined! Let us follow our natural instinct and ask right away:

## **WHOSE FAULT IS THIS?**

### CLP(FD) CONSTRAINTS TO BLAME?

In fact, it turns out that using a declarative formulation has simply **exposed an ambiguity in the task formulation**. Prematurely committing to one of the solutions does not expose this problem.

What was probably *meant* was a task description that induces the following relation between an integer and the output:

```
integer_output(N, 'Fuzz')     :- N #= 3*_, N mod 5 #\= 0.
integer_output(N, 'Buzz')     :- N #= 5*_, N mod 3 #\= 0.
integer_output(N, 'FizzBuzz') :- N #= 3*_, N #= 5*_.
integer_output(N, N)          :- N mod 3 #\= 0, N mod 5 #\= 0.
```

This yields:

```
?- integer_output(15, O).
O = 'FizzBuzz' ;
false.
```

The other test cases still work as expected.

Now, using this relation as a building block, it is easy to *lift* it to *lists* of integers, using the meta-predicate `maplist/3`:

```
fizz_buzz(Ls) :-
        numlist(1, 100, Ls0),
        maplist(integer_output, Ls0, Ls).
```

Sample query and answer:

```
?- fizz_buzz(Ls).
Ls = [1, 2, 'Fuzz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fuzz', 7, 8, 'Fuzz'|...] ;
false.
```

Note that we are *not* writing anything ourselves: We are using the Prolog **toplevel** to do the writing for us, and reason about **arguments**.

The advantage is clear: We can *again* write test cases for such a predicate. For example, we expect the following to hold, and it does:

```
?- Ls = [1,2|_], fizz_buzz(Ls).
Ls = [1, 2, 'Fuzz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fuzz', 7, 8, 'Fuzz'|...] .
```

So far, everything is completely pure and usable in all directions. I leave *formatting* such solutions as you want as an easy exercise.

If your Prolog system does not provide `numlist/3`, you can use **`bagof/3`** to obtain the list of integers from 1 to 100 like this:

```
?- bagof(L, (L in 1..100,indomain(L)), Ls).
Ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

Thus, `bagof/3` can be useful for this task, but I cannot recommend to use it for side-effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid that you might be missing one important detail of the solution in my question: I only need to define two cases, "divisible by 3" and "divisible by 5", and neither needs to know about the other. Then, `bagof/3` lets me pick the one, the other, both, or neither. Imagine I add "divisible by 7" and "divisible by 11" to the problem statement: this makes exactly 4 cases to cover. So this is why I considered using `bagof/3` and this is why I asked the question. I thought this was kind of self-explanatory.

Comment: see also [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272898/using-bagof-3-only-for-the-side-effect/43174496#comment19817308_14274125) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43117208/1812457).

Comment: I have to admit: this was a misguided question, and I asked it very soon after I started trying to write Prolog code. It gathered quite a few answers, and got a bit of new attention lately, so I am not going to edit it. However, I want to point out that no one tried to address the actual question, which makes it obvious that it is not a good question. [This new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43117208/1812457) addresses the obvious problem and tries to fix it. I personally think this is _good enough_.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `bagof/3` you could use [`if/3`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dif.html), like so:

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate), [forall/2]).
:- use_module(library(between),  [between/3]).

fizzbuzz :-
   forall(between(1,100,Z),  fizzbuzz(Z)).

fizzbuzz(Z) :-
   forall(if(integer_fb(Z,X), true, Z=X),  write(X)),
   write(' ').

integer_fb(Z, 'Fizz') :- Z rem 3 =:= 0.
integer_fb(Z, 'Buzz') :- Z rem 5 =:= 0.
```

Sample output using SICStus Prolog 4.4.0:

```
| ?- fizzbuzz.
1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 19 Buzz Fizz 22 23 Fizz Buzz 26 Fizz 28 29 FizzBuzz 31 32 Fizz 34 Buzz Fizz 37 38 Fizz Buzz 41 Fizz 43 44 FizzBuzz 46 47 Fizz 49 Buzz Fizz 52 53 Fizz Buzz 56 Fizz 58 59 FizzBuzz 61 62 Fizz 64 Buzz Fizz 67 68 Fizz Buzz 71 Fizz 73 74 FizzBuzz 76 77 Fizz 79 Buzz Fizz 82 83 Fizz Buzz 86 Fizz 88 89 FizzBuzz 91 92 Fizz 94 Buzz Fizz 97 98 Fizz Buzz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort of pattern matching :

```
fizzbuzz :-
    forall( between(1, 100, X), fizzbuzz(X) ).
fizzbuzz(X) :-
    0 is X rem 15,
    format('~w FizzBuzz~n', [X]).

fizzbuzz(X) :-
    0 is X rem 5,
    format('~w Buzz~n', [X]).

fizzbuzz(X) :-
    0 is X mod 3,
    format('~w Fizz~n', [X]).

fizzbuzz(X) :-
    write(X), nl.
```

Comment: I considered doing it like this, but I guess I was looking for a general solution for the following situation: try all possible solutions to a goal, or revert to a default if none fits. The more I think about it the more it seems that `bagof/3` and a semicolon is a perfectly fine way of doing it. Your solution works in this case, but it is specific to this problem only.

Comment: "I was looking for a general solution for the following situation: try all possible solutions to a goal, or revert to a default if none fits" - one way to do this in prolog is : consider a variable A , if A is 1 then B is "hel0" , it A is 2 then B is "g00dbye" , if A is anything else B is invalid : ?- (A=1|A=2|A=3|A=4),((A=1,B='hel0')*->(true);(A=2,B='g00dbye')*->(true);(A=_,B='invalid')) .

Comment: Another (better?) way , which I seem to have invented , is to specify your options as disjoints within an expression and then evaluate the expression once . i.e : ?- (A=1|A=2|A=3|A=4),once(((A=1,B='hel0')|(A=2,B='goodbye')|(A=_,B='invalid'))) . When once is provided a series of disjoint goals in this manner , it will evaluate the goals from left-to-right but stop evaluation at the first of the goals that is true .

Comment: However 99% of prolog code follows this pattern instead :  [user] . a(A,B) :- (A=1,!,B='hel0'). a(A,B) :- A=2,!,B='goodbye'. a(A,B) :- A=_,!,B='invalid' . ^D ?- (A=1|A=2|A=3|A=4),a(A,B).

Answer (score 1):

aggregate(count, fb(X), C) allows to count solutions, but is based on bagof, thus builds the list just to count the elements. Then I wrote a reusable 'building block', predating call_nth/2, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400256/874024) @false answer

```
:- meta_predicate count_solutions(0, ?).

count_solutions(Goal, C) :-
    State = count(0, _), % note the extra argument which remains a variable
    (   Goal,
        arg(1, State, C1),
        C2 is C1 + 1,
        nb_setarg(1, State, C2),
        fail
    ;   arg(1, State, C)
    ).
```

the 'applicative' code become

```
:- use_module(uty, [count_solutions/2]).

fizzbuzz :- forall( between(1, 100, X), fizzbuzz(X) ).
fizzbuzz(X) :-
    ( count_solutions(fb(X), 0) -> write(X) ; true ), nl.

fb(X) :- X rem 3 =:= 0, write('Fizz').
fb(X) :- X rem 5 =:= 0, write('Buzz').
```

Comment: You are not counting solutions but answers.

Answer (score 1):

I take the idea of @Kintalken and I just do minimal change in your original code to arrive at this solution:

```
fizzbuzz :-
    forall( between(1, 100, X),
        (   fizzbuzz(X, Output),
            format("~w~n", [Output])
        )).

fizzbuzz(X, Output) :-
    (   bagof(Y, fb(X, Y), Ys)
    ->  atomic_list_concat(Ys, Output)
    ;   X = Output
    ).

fb(X, 'Fizz') :- X rem 3 =:= 0.
fb(X, 'Buzz') :- X rem 5 =:= 0.
```

The only change from the code in your question is that first I collect solutions then I print in one place only and not as side effect of predicate that is collected with `bagof` so you no more have to have side effect inside `bagof`.

Also as you see now printing is in the second argument of `forall` so that it is clear where side effects are happening and not hiding elsewhere and there is exactly one place for all side effect of this program not scattered between clauses of different predicates.

Another thing is that instead of conjunction I use `->` not because it is any different but because it conveys intention to use `bagof` to collect solution or do something else if there are no solutions. When I read your question and answers and comments to answers this was part of the discussion?

I do not know how to indent exactly the contents of `forall`. The way I have indented looks maybe ok but maybe not ok at all. `between` and `fizzbuzz` and `format` are now aligned but only `fizzbuzz` and `format` should have been aligned, but `between` aligned by accident so this is not on purpose, maybe it is confusing, but I don't like to have something like this

```
forall(
    between(1, 100, X),
    (   fizzbuzz(X, Output),
        format("~w~n", [Output])
    ))
```

because then `forall(` looks so lonely all alone by itself on a whole line without anything to help it feel less lonely with its sad little opening paren.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are already using it; `forall/2`:

```
write_fb(X) :-
    forall(fb(X), true).
```

Alternatively, you can change your representation of the problem:

```
write_fb(X) :-
  (X rem 3 =:= 0 -> write('Fizz') ; true),
  (X rem 5 =:= 0 -> write('Buzz') ; true).
```

Of course, in this case, using `bagof/3` and friends is fine since the generated list is very small.

Comment: I also suggested using forall, but I was wrong: consider that bagof **fails** when there are no soultions...

Comment: forall does something different; as for using conditions... not really clean and general enough. As I said already in response to the other answer, I think bagof is actually exactly what I am looking for: create all solutions or fail if there is no solution. The problem I had with using a side effect instead of collecting the result is, I suppose, that Prolog predicates are not meant to be used for their side effects, normally. Thank you for answering anyway!

Answer (score 0):

My esteemed collegues have answered, but you want 'between'.

You don't need to collect the solutions. In that your intuition is correct.
I suspect you started with something like

```
fizzbuzz :-  between(1, 100, N),
             fb(N).


fb(N) :-  N rem 5 =:= 0,  
          N rem 3 =:= 0,
          write(fizzbuzz).

fb(N) :-  N rem 5 =:= 0,    
          write(buzz).

fb(N) :-  N rem 3 =:= 0,
          write(fizz).

fb(N) :-  write(N).
```

the problem with this is that fb isn't 'steadfast' - 
you don't expect it to offer you multiple solutions, but it does -
for example, fb(15) unifies with every fb rule.

The solution is to force it to be steadfast, using a cut:

```
fizzbuzz :-  between(1, 100, N),
             fb(N).


fb(N) :-  N rem 5 =:= 0,  
          N rem 3 =:= 0,
          !,
          write(fizzbuzz).

fb(N) :-  N rem 5 =:= 0,
          !,    
          write(buzz).

fb(N) :-  N rem 3 =:= 0,
          !,
          write(fizz).

fb(N) :-  write(N).
```

Comment: The notion of *steadfastness* and *steadfast* are well established in Prolog, but they mean something different.

Comment: Really?  Can you amplify on that?  I thought steadfast meant 'ok to backtrack into'

Comment: Steadfastness was coined by O'Keefe in 1987. See the PROLOG Digest of 1987-10-02, Vol. 5 : 71. I have been searching it without success with google. Seems google has removed postings of that time... The notion has gathered some interest recently due to the need of a precise definition for ISO/IEC (WD)TR 13211-3. See: [these comments for a definition](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/comments-dcgs-draft-2010-04-01.html) and [these documents of WG17](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#dcg).

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm being dense here. I know there's a current discussion of steadfast in phrase/3 but not sure how it's relevant to my use of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Me...I'd do something like:

```
fizzbuzz( X , Y ) :-
  X =< Y ,
  R3 is X % 3 ,
  R5 is X % 5 ,
  map( R3 , R5 , X , V ) ,
  write(V) ,
  nl ,
  X1 is X+1 ,
  fizzbuzz( X1 , Y )
  .

map( 0 , 0 , _ , fizzbuzz ) :- ! .
map( 0 , _ , _ , fizz     ) :- ! .
map( _ , 0 , _ , buzz     ) :- ! .
map( _ , _ , X , X        ) :- ! .
```

Answer (score 0):

Why abuse `bagof/3` for the side effect and just stop there? We can also abuse circular lists:

```
fizzbuzz :-
        Fizz = [fail,fail,write('Fizz')|Fizz],
        Buzz = [fail,fail,fail,fail,write('Buzz')|Buzz],
        fb(1, 100, Fizz, Buzz).

fb(N, N, _, _) :- !.
fb(N, Last, [F|Fs], [B|Bs]) :-
        (       bagof(_, ( F ; B ), _)
        ->      true
        ;       write(N)
        ),
        nl,
        succ(N, N1),
        fb(N1, Last, Fs, Bs).
```

Comment: Please note that a unification like `X = f(X)` is subject to occurs check (STO), and this example won't work if your Prolog system implements the occurs check to make unifications sound.

Comment: @mat The relative frequency of "abuse" in the text above (excluding the Prolog code) is 11.8%

Comment: @mat There is also a cut, if-then-else, side effects, and (especially proud of this) lists of goals.

Comment: @mat Still a bit sad that no one ever gave even an upvote for my question, or **any of the answers** (except for me), even though I would assume that every person who answered must have read the question and at least some of the answers.... I guess this makes this a legit shitpost.

Comment: I must admit that I stopped reading your question after seeing "for the side effect". Now that I have read it, it becomes somewhat clear that you seem to want to attain the opposite of what the title states...

Comment: @mat but the question *is* about using bagof for the side effect?

Comment: Yes, I guess in the same sense as "avoiding chemotherapy to cure cancer" is about applying chemotherapy to cure cancer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

> Print all numbers from 1 to 100, but instead of the number, print 'Fuzz' if number is a multiple of 3, 'Buzz' if multiple of 5, and 'FizzBuzz' if both.

I think the fact that you encountered this peculiarity about bagof is an indication of a "smell" in your program. I find that happens to me a lot with Prolog. Prolog is actually a very minimal kit with not very much provided. I have learned over time that if I encounter a need for something that is NOT in that minimal kit, or my usage seems to betray the intended usage of a builtin feature, then almost always it is because there is a "smell" in my current approach.

More about "smell" here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

I think the "smell" in your current approach becomes apparent when we outline a general sketch of the procedural flow that your program currently entails:

1. generate
2. print
3. transform

The problem is that you are trying to "print" BEFORE you "transform" .
You want to "print" AFTER you "transform", like this:

1. generate
2. transform
3. print

With this in mind we can rewrite the problem statement:

The NEW problem:

Solve for all each number:

> Generate each number from 1 to 100, but transform each number into an each message, into each message 'Fuzz' if the each number is a multiple of 3, into each message 'Buzz' if the each number is a multiple of 5, into each message 'FizzBuzz' if the each number is both, then print each message.

The following is a program that aims to solve the above stated problem.

The program listing is followed by an example query session.

```
*/

/* -- prolog setup -- */

:-  ( op(10'1150,'yfx','forall')    )   .

:-  ( op(10'1150,'fy','if') )   .
:-  ( op(10'1140,'yfx','then') )    .
:-  ( op(10'1140,'yfx','else') )    .

(if IF then THEN else ELSE) :- (IF *-> THEN ; ELSE) .
(if IF then THEN) :- (IF *-> THEN ; (throw(false(IF)))) .

term_expansion((if IF then THEN else ELSE),((IF :- THEN *-> (true) ; ELSE)))    .
term_expansion((if IF then THEN),((IF :- THEN *-> (true) ; (throw(false(IF))))))    .

/* -- program -- */

if
(
  program(_)
)
then
(
  (
    if
    (
      generate(NUMBER)
    )
    then
    (
      true
    )
  )
  forall
  (
    if
    (
      transform(NUMBER,MESSAGE)
    )
    then
    (
      if
      (
        accept(NUMBER,MESSAGE)
      )
      then
      (
        if
        (
          echo(NUMBER)
        )
        then
        (
          echo(MESSAGE)
        )
      )
      else
      (
        true
      )
    )
  )
)
.

if
(
  generate(NUMBER)
)
then
(
  between(1,100,NUMBER)
)
.

if
(
  transform(NUMBER,MESSAGE)
)
then
(
  if
  (
    multiple_of_3(NUMBER)
  )
  then
  (
    if
    (
      multiple_of_5(NUMBER)
    )
    then
    (
      MESSAGE='FizzBuzz'
    )
    else
    (
      MESSAGE='Fuzz'
    )
  )
  else
  (
    if
    (
      multiple_of_5(NUMBER)
    )
    then
    (
      MESSAGE='Buzz'
    )
    else
    (
      % this contingency is undefined in the problem statement %
      true
    )
  )
)
.

if
(
  multiple_of_3(NUMBER)
)
then
(
  NUMBER rem 10'3 =:= 10'0
)
else
(
  false
)
.

if
(
  multiple_of_5(NUMBER)
)
then
(
  NUMBER rem 10'5 =:= 10'0
)
else
(
  false
)
.

if
(
  accept(NUMBER,MESSAGE)
)
then
(
  if
  (
    true
  )
  then
  (
    true
  )
  else
  (
    false
  )
)
else
(
  false
)
.

if
(
  echo(MESSAGE)
)
then
(
  if
  (
    writeq(MESSAGE)
  )
  then
  (
    nl
  )
)
.

/*

example query
=============

?-
program(_)
.

3
'Fuzz'
5
'Buzz'
6
'Fuzz'
9
'Fuzz'
12
'Fuzz'
15
'FizzBuzz'
18
'Fuzz'

[ ... and so on as expected ... ]

90
'FizzBuzz'
93
'Fuzz'
95
'Buzz'
96
'Fuzz'
99
'Fuzz'
100
'Buzz'
true.

?-
```

However, the program as currently presented does not quite produce the intended output as presented above.

In the program above there is a marker:

```
  % this contingency is undefined in the problem statement %
```

Issue needs to be resolved before the program is 100% satisfactory.

Tested using swi-prolog and yap.

Comment: Well, so your solution is incorrect, isn't it? Or I am missing something important that you have managed to hide within the _very_ unusual coding style and formatting.

Comment: I give you upvote because you gave me good idea for answer but your solution has too much code I do not understand so I do not know if it is good or bad but still your "1. generate 2. transform 3. print" idea is good!

Comment: " your solution has too much code" -- challenge accepted !

Comment: @Kintalken "too much code _I do not understand_" sorry I should use more commas to make myself better understood so that I do not get misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

/*

## problem statement

```
solve for all each number   :
```

generate each number from 1 to 100  ,
    but transform each number into an each message  ,
        into each message 'Fuzz' if the each number is a multiple of 3  ,
        into each message 'Buzz' if the each number is a multiple of 5  ,
        into each message 'FizzBuzz' if the each number is both ,
    then print each message .

*/

/*

## program

*/

```
    :- use_module(library(clpfd)) .

    :- op(10'1,'yfx','forall') .
    :- op(10'1,'fy','once') .

    (
        program
    )
    :-
    (
        (
            between(1,100,NUMBER)
        )
        forall
        (
            once
            (
                (
                    MESSAGE='FizzBuzz'
                    ,
                    NUMBER rem 10'3 #= 10'0
                    ,
                    NUMBER rem 10'5 #= 10'0
                )
                |
                (
                    MESSAGE='Buzz'
                    ,
                    NUMBER rem 10'5 #= 10'0
                )
                |
                (
                    MESSAGE='Fuzz'
                    ,
                    NUMBER rem 10'3 #= 10'0
                )
                |
                (
                    MESSAGE=_
                )
            )
            ,
            once
            (
                (
                    nonvar(MESSAGE)
                    ,
                    writeq(NUMBER)
                    ,
                    nl
                    ,
                    writeq(MESSAGE)
                    ,
                    nl
                )
                |
                (
                    true
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .
```

/*

## testing

Tested in swi prolog .
*/

```
    ?- program .

    3
    'Fuzz'
    5
    'Buzz'
    6
    'Fuzz'
    9
    'Fuzz'
    10
    'Buzz'
    12
    'Fuzz'
    15
    'FizzBuzz'

    { .e.t.c. | ... as expected ... |  .e.t.c. }

    99
    'Fuzz'
    100
    'Buzz'
    true.

    ?-
```

*/

Comment: you do realize this is not the problem statement, right? should be 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14, FizzBuzz, 16, etc.