# Finding up to N unique solutions of a goal in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Could you tell me how to find up to N unique solutions of a goal in Prolog?

I know using findall/3 all the solutions of a goal can be found, but for a goal which has too many, or infinite solutions, I want to find only up to N unique solutions if it is enough.

What I want to do is like this:

```
?- find_unique_n(10, X, any_goal(X), Xs).
Xs = [...] % up to 10 unique solutions.
```

If the total number of the unique solutions for a goal is below N, I want to find all of them.

Edit:
As false pointed out, itt was not clear what 'unique solutions' means. If sample_goal/1 is defined as below:

```
sample_goal(1).
sample_goal(1).
sample_goal(2).
sample_goal(2).
```

the expected results are:

```
?- find_unique_n(1, X, sample_goal(X), Xs).
Xs = [1]
?- find_unique_n(2, X, sample_goal(X), Xs).
Xs = [1,2]
?- find_unique_n(3, X, sample_goal(X), Xs).
Xs = [1,2]
```

And for goals with infinite solutions, the expected results are:

```
?- find_unique_n(2, X, (repeat, between(1,2,X)), Xs).
Xs = [1,2]
?- find_unique_n(3, X, (repeat, between(1,2,X)), Xs).
% This won't stop, it's ok
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog: "findall" for limited number of solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852980/prolog-findall-for-limited-number-of-solutions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, although not particularly efficient.  The idea is to repeatedly call (copies of) Goal, looking for solutions that are not yet in the Sols list:

```
find_unique_n(N, X, Goal, Xs) :-
    find_unique_n(N, X, Goal, Xs, []).

find_unique_n(N, X, Goal, Xs, Sols) :-
    N > 0,
    copy_term(X-Goal, CX-CGoal),
    call(CGoal),
    \+ (member(Sol,Sols), variant(Sol,CX)),
    !,
    N1 is N-1,
    Xs = [CX|Xs1],
    Sols1 = [CX|Sols],
    find_unique_n(N1, X, Goal, Xs1, Sols1).
find_unique_n(_N, _X, _Goal, [], _Sols).
```

If your solutions are all ground, you can use ==/2 in place of variant/2.

Alternatively, if your Prolog has convenient primitives to save data across backtracking, you can use a failure-driven approach like in the following [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) example:

```
find_unique_n(N, X, Goal, Xs) :-
    store_create(Solutions),
    (
        once((
            call(Goal),
            store_set(Solutions, X, _),
            store_count(Solutions) >= N
        )),
        fail
    ;
        stored_keys(Solutions, Xs)
    ).
```

where the store-primitives implement a non-backtrackable hash table.  Similar solutions using assert/retract are possible, but nontrival to make reentrant and memory leak free.

Comment: There is no reason why assert/retract precludes a reentrant solution. It would not be very space efficient, though

Answer (score 4):

### Answers vs. solutions

From your question it is not clear what you mean by "unique solutions". After all, you say:

> If the total number of the unique solutions for a goal is below N, I want to find all of them.

Consider the goal `(X = 1, repeat)`. The total number of unique solutions is one. But still, you will not be able to stop, since you do not know whether or not you found all solutions. So if `N` is greater than 1, you have to loop. Or consider `( repeat, between(1,10,N) )` here there are ten unique solutions, so if `N` is below or equal 10 you can find them all, and terminate.

Please note that Prolog produces answers that may contain solutions. Typically, you get an **answer substitution** that is not necessarily ground. Think of `X = t(_).` This answer contains infinitely many solutions, like `X = t(1)`, `X = t(2)` etc.

Most probably you wanted to see the first `N` answers. A solution to that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20866206/772868).

Taking your question literally (that is: always terminating goal, ground answers), simply wrap `setof(t,Goal,_)` around the goal.

Comment: I admit it was unclear as you pointed out. What I want to do is find up to N unique solutions of a goal which can have a large number of finite solutions, not infinite ones, so assume that a goal will fail eventually.

Comment: and please assume that solutions are always ground.

Comment: @CapelliC: Your deleted answer is worth a comment!

Comment: You mean `findfirstn(N, X, setof(t,any_goal(X),_), Xs)`? When the goal is `between(1,10000000,_), X = 1` your answer will call it 10000000 times even if N is 1, that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: @user1639561: Please read [help] -> [Tour] to get an idea how SO works. There is a lot of second-guessing here.

Answer (score 2):

After your clarifications, this is a very compact solution, that contains also some reusable predicates, see [this answer for `call_firstn/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20866206/772868) and the other predicates.

```
find_unique_n(N, X, Goal_0, Xs) :-
   findall(X, call_firstn(call_nub(Goal_0), N), Xs).
```

So the nub is `call_nub/1` below. Nub, as in [`nub`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nub).

Caveat: This version requires `setup_call_cleanup/3` or `call_cleanup/2` to work properly and it does not work together with constraints.

```
:- dynamic(nub_answer_id/2).
:- dynamic(generated_id/1).

:- meta_predicate(call_nub(0)). % only for SICStus/SWI/YAP
call_nub(Goal_0) :-
   setup_call_cleanup(
      genid(Id),
      (  term_to_vec(Goal_0, Vec),
         Goal_0,
         (  \+nub_answer_id(Vec, Id)
         -> true
         ;  \+ ( nub_answer_id(XVec, Id), subsumes_term(XVec, Vec) )
         ),
         asserta(nub_answer_id(Vec, Id))
      ),
      retractall(nub_answer_id(_,Id))
   ).

term_to_vec(T, Vec) :-
   term_variables(T, Vs),
   catch(Vec=..[v|Vs],error(representation_error(max_arity),_),T=Vec).

genid(Id) :-
   (  generated_id(Id0) -> true ; Id0 = 0 ),
   Id1 is Id0 + 1,
   asserta(generated_id(Id1)),
   retractall(generated_id(Id0)),
   Id1 = Id.

setup_call_cleanup(Setup_0, Call_0, Cleanup_0) :- % only for SICStus
   once(Setup_0),
   call_cleanup(Call_0, once(Cleanup_0)).
```