# Prolog: findall but to save only some solutions

Tags: list, prolog

I found [that for swi-prolog it exists findnsols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212369/6999690), however, it is not working for me.

My `predicate generate_color(Color)` generates random colors for [html](/questions/tagged/html).

When I try to call it N times and save the values ​​of the executions in a list I always get a single result instead of many.

```
findnsols(3, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).
```

> Colors = ["# 4c4b43"].

```
findnsols(3, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).
```

> Colors = ["# 158955"].

```
findnsols (300, Color, generate_color (Color), Colors).
```

> Colors = ["# 5d67e1"].

Does anyone know of any way that I can get even the Nsolutions I want in a list?

Expected output:

```
findnsols(3, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).
```

> Colors = ["# 5d67e1", "# 4c4b43", "# 158955"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `generate_color` only returns a single color (i.e., you cannot press `;` after the first solution is given).

Thus, `findnsols` does not work, since it works based on *backtracking*, i.e., entering your Goal again and trying to find further solutions.

I suggest a solution similar to the following:

```
length(Colors, 10), maplist(generate_color, Colors).
```

This defines a list `Colors` of length 10, where all entries must correspond to `generate_color` (for more infos see [`maplist`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/2))

---

Related example:

`random` generates *a single random number*.

```
?- findnsols(3, N, random(0, 100, N), Rands).
Rands = [33].

?- length(Rands, 10), maplist(random(0,100), Rands).
Rands = [85, 92, 81, 66, 98, 15, 74, 95, 56|...].
```

Comment: worked like a charm! you can try to solve the exercise yourself, your answer was for the unit tests: https://www.codewars.com/kata/56f1c6034d0c330e4a001059/prolog

Answer (score 1):

To have a predicate that generates multiple random colors,
its not enough to do:
(the 0x syntax is from ISO core standard, an integer notation in base 16)

```
generate_color(Color) :-
   random(0, 0xFFFFFF, Color).
```

If you call the above, it only generates one solution:
(not to be used in the browser, just integer in base 10 shown)

```
?- generate_color(Color).
Color = 8649520.
```

If you want to make an infinite generator,
you have to place repeat/0:

```
generate_color(Color) :-
   repeat,
   random(0, 0xFFFFFF, Color).
```

It then works as follows:

```
?- generate_color(Color).
Color = 4282662 ;
Color = 13523844 ;
Color = 511176 ;
Etc..
```

Instead of using repeat/0, you can also program generate_color/1
tail recursive to have it return multiple solutions.

**Edit 04.09.2021:**
In SWI-Prolog you can use [format/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) to convert to base 16,
to get something that can be then used inside the browser:

```
?- generate_color(Color), format('#~|~`0t~16r~6+', [Color]).
#415926
C = 4282662 ;
#ce5b84
C = 13523844 ;
#07ccc8
C = 511176.
Etc..
```

Comment: interesting solution however those colors are not valid html color. you can verify it at https://www.codewars.com/kata/56f1c6034d0c330e4a001059/prolog

Comment: You have to convert the decimal number into a hex number with 6 hex digits. See the 4 nibbles example in the comment section here https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2

Comment: however that produes problems when trying to pass regex based unit tests: `generate_color(Color) :-repeat,random(0, 0xFFFFFF, AColor),Color = [AColor],format('#~|~`0t~16r~6+', Color).` atom_chars/2: Type error: `atom' expected, found `[14906927]' (a list)

Comment: You need to use format/3 (the termary predicate) to obtain some resut and not have it written on the output stream. What I showed was only format/2 (binary predicate). Read the documentation to figure out how to use it.