# SWI Prolog (swipl) shows all the variables I used, I only want one shown

Tags: prolog

I'm running this code:

```
findall(A, syllable(A), X), nth1(1001,X,B).
```

syllable returns a valid syllable as a list of sounds. i.e. [e,g,g,s].
I just want to know the 1001st possible syllable, B = [θ,i,p]. And I get that printed to the screen. But after B is shown, prolog shows all of X. Which is approximately 40000 different syllables. This is too much information for me.

How can I hide X from being shown or just have B shown?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a 'projection':

```
sy(B) :- findall(A, syllable(A), X), nth1(1001,X,B).
```

or better, instead of building a full list just to peek one element, define [`call_nth/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364634/count-the-number-of-calls-of-a-clause/11400256#11400256)
and then 'jump to' the right solution

```
?- call_nth(syllable(B), 1001).
```