# Prolog: pattern matching within a list

Tags: prolog, dcg

Define a relation xyz(X) that is true if X is a xyz sequence. A xyz sequence is a sequence that consists of either the number 0, or the number 1 followed by two other xyz sequences.

Some xyz sequences:

```
xyz([0]).
xyz([1,0,1,0,0]).
```

And, the following are **not** considered xyz sequences:

```
xyz([1,1,0,0]).
xyz([0,1,0]).
xyz([1,1,0]).
xyz([1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]).
```

Can someone help me with how to approach this problem?

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313936/solution-to-smullyans-numerical-machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to write a DCG. See [this tutorial](http://www.logic.at/prolog/dcg.html) for a thorough introduction. You can literally write down the problem statement verbatim to get a solution:

```
xyz --> [0].
xyz --> [1], xyz, xyz.
```

You will need `phrase`:

```
?- phrase(xyz, [1,0,1,0,0]).
```

This solution leaves behind a choice point.

Comment: I didn't know about DCG before, it looks like some powerful stuff. I appreciate you sharing that information. How would I go about implementing those DCG rules within the `xyz(A)` predicate so that to get 'true', I don't have to type in `phrase(xyz, [0])' and instead I can query with `xyz([0]`?

Comment: Never mind, it was pretty simple. `xyz(A):- phrase(xyz,A).` after those DCG rules. Looks good, right?

Comment: @am3decoy Yes, this is pretty much it, if you don't want to call `phrase` yourself in your predicate. It is up to you if you want to be explicit about the call to `phrase` of if you want to hide it: I prefer to use it directly, but this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @am3decoy And keep in mind that a DCG is not exactly the same as pattern matching: you write a grammar, not just a pattern (as in regex).

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to be looking into this further. Hey if you don't mind, do you think you can look at one of my other questions? I have it figured out thanks to one of the users here, I just need to know how to reverse the list. I tried different ways to reverse the list, but I had no success. The code is `xyz(X, Y):- f(X, Z,_) -> findall([A|B], (member(A, Z), xyz(A, B)), L), flatten(L, F), sort(F, Y); Y = [].` I simply need the list that gets outputted by this in reverse. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845949/recursion-in-prolog/28850778?noredirect=1#comment45994124_28850778

Comment: @am3decoy You have already gotten an answer, and you have accepted it. In such cases, instead of editing your question, adding to it, it is best to ask a _new_ question. So go ahead and do it. You can pretty much copy the second part of the original question to a new question. You can also link your own old question in the new question, if you feel it is useful.

Comment: That makes sense since it's going to be available to others who are seeking assistance with the same issue. I've created a new post. Please take a look at your earliest. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894594/prolog-need-help-reversing-a-list

Answer (score 0):

such simple grammar is ideal to understand the mechanism (albeit simplified) that powers DCGs:

```
seq(S) :- seq(S, []).

seq([0|R], R).
seq([1|T], R) :- seq(T, Q), seq(Q, R).
```