# how to define (sometimes) recursive prolog trees

Tags: prolog, dcg

I've got two different types of sentences to parse, but i'll just give them simples names for now. Basically, I have two parse trees

```
1.
A --> A , pp

A --> dv, np

2.
A --> tv, np
```

I hope that makes sense, I just have no idea how to program this in prolog without getting into lots of loops! Any help would be great, also please let me know if i can provide more information (first time using stack overflow)

Comment: Can you describe what it is you're actually trying to create? A predicate that does what? Can you give an example of desired input and output? Can you show any attempts you've made at solving the problem?

Comment: Not completely clear what is your input and what you expect your output to be, but seems similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893265/prolog-pattern-matching-within-a-list