# Getting the nth solution of a query

Tags: prolog

Can I extract the nth solution of a query? I'm aware of `findall`, but I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that it creates an entire list of solutions, and I'd prefer an approach that consumes only as much memory as needed to compute the value.

Comment: See false's `call_nth/2` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400256).

Comment: @mat thank you, I'll likely go with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way in which you can let SWI-Prolog calculate exactly *N* solutions (where you can supply the number *N* yourself).

In this example *N* is 17 and the goal whose 17th solution we're interested in is `between(0, inf, I)`:

```
?- findnsols(17, I, between(0, inf, I), L), last(L, X), !.
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8|...],
X = 16.
```

Notice the use of the cut in order to force determinism. With the cut `findnsols/4` may be used for pagination (i.e., in order to calculate the next 17 solutions).

Comment: Downside: this requires space proportional to `N`.