# In GNU-Prolog, can I 'catch' a linux signal?

Tags: linux, prolog, gnu-prolog

Is there a way to 'trap' (e.g. 'catch') an operating system signal within GNU Prolog? (I'm using Ubuntu/Linux, latest gprolog).

I think a long time ago I used this approach in WAMCC, before that morphed into GNU Prolog:

```
:- catch(Long_Running_Goal,signal(2),write('program interrupted'))
```

But if I test this using a (repeat,fail) infinite loop with, for example

```
:- catch((repeat,fail),X,write(X)).
```

In the interpreter Ctrl-C still takes me to the trace/debugger, and the compiled program just quits if I interrupt it with `kill -1`, `kill -2` etc.

I've tried compiling the program with `--no-top-level` in case the default toplevel somehow captures the signal, but that made no difference.

SWI-Prolog seems to have a suitable built-in predicate `on_signal` which serves the purpose but I'm looking for a solution with gprolog if that's possible.

Comment: Hi - still hoping for some help on this... but in the meantime I can comment that the reason for the requirement is a parallel-processing experimental approach where the Prolog executable can be interrupted by another process, and at that point if coughs up a 'state' value that represents its progress in the current search such that the processing can be split up from that point and assigned to other processors.  There's plent of work in this area but my approach rather depends on this interrupt capability which *was* there in wamcc.

Comment: @Bamb: sounds much like Condor. How large is that state? As a bottom-feeder, I wrote out a state regularly.

Comment: I've just worked out where a 'bounty' comes from... thanks false.

Comment: You missed my question above?

Comment: Maybe you can describe the precise state you have? My experience is rather not to mess with signals, for I happened to be just on the bleeding edge. There are lots of techniques to avoid this. Extra question?

Comment: @false: I am actually using Condor for the Prolog worker processes although the prolog is spawned as a child of a more persistent C process that participates in a botnet (the original Skynet, not including the mythical movie version). But the 'state' is a fancy concept - it is actually a short sequence of integers representing a path through the (pure) Prolog search tree, which can be used to reconstruct the actual state...

Comment: My key requirement is to be able to interrupt the prolog program and have it print something I can use. Eg it would be simple if I could catch(myprog, X, write(abc)) where the catch gets triggered by a signal...

Comment: Looks very much like the config I had - except that my processes only ran at night. Interrupts challenge a Prolog system - you will have 0 chance to reproduce them. In many situations you can compress search trees using [`call_nth/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400256/772868) down to a couple of  integers. Thus writing is something like 50 bytes...

Comment: Thanks false.. I checked out call_nth and (nested) it is similar to what I'm doing.

Comment: Not sure you got it :-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [mescalinum](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1044117) who confirmed [signal handling is not available by default in GNU Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31015884).

But GNU Prolog has excellent support for user routines in C, and I've been able to write a small amount of C code which catches the Linux signal and triggers (if required) a Prolog exception (note mine is Ubuntu 14.04/GNU Prolog 1.3.0 so C type for `init_signal` function is `Bool` from gprolog.h - this changed in gprolog.h 1.3.1 onwards to `PlBool` - see [1.3.0](http://www.cs.csubak.edu/docs/gprolog/gprolog065.html%201.3.0) vs [most recent](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html) manuals):

C code "signal.c":

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <gprolog.h>

/* signal handler */
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGHUP)
  {
    printf("received SIGHUP\n");
    /* throw Prolog exception */
    Pl_Err_Instantiation();
  }
}

/* GNU Prolog  goal that registers the signal handler */
/* declared with :- foreign(init_signal).             */
Bool init_signal()
{
  if (signal(SIGHUP, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
  {
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGHUP\n");
  }
  printf("%s","SIGHUP handler registered\n");
  return TRUE;                  /* succeed */
}
```

Test usage in Prolog "test.pl" - the "long-running" query in this example is o_query, used in a 'catch' relation and can be interrupted with SIGHUP:

```
:- foreign(init_signal).

:- initialization(main).

main :- write('Prolog signal test program started'),
        nl,
        init_signal,
        catch(o_query,X,write('Prolog exception thrown')),
        nl,
        halt.

o_query :- repeat,
           sleep(1),
           fail.
```

Compile with `gplc test.pl signal.c`

Now if the program is run with ./test it can be interrupted from another terminal with `kill -1 <test process id>`

```
Bambam@desktop:~/prolog/signal$ ./test
Prolog signal test program started
SIGHUP handler registered
received SIGHUP
Prolog exception thrown
Bambam@desktop:~/prolog/signal$
```

For my purposes, I can usefully handle the incoming exception while I'm in the C signal handler, but reflecting it back to a Prolog 'throw' (in this case with a 'instantiation error') keeps the code tidily within Prolog.

The reason I want to be able to send (and catch) a signal to the executing GNU Prolog process is because my system is a high-performance parallel processing Prolog environment which can trigger any long-running Prolog process to dynamically 'split' itself into multiple parts which then execute on other machines. But you fundamentally cannot (with my method) predict the exact distribution of work and in due course other processors will be interrupted (i.e. sent a signal) to further split the workload.

Comment: When will a process split? How often does this occur? In my experience it is rather (foreseen) downtime which is a problem with massively parallel tasks.

Comment: "When will a process split? How often does this occur?" - [link](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/221792)

Comment: I get currently for the link "an error has occured `java.lang.NullPointerException: `"

Comment: Thanks! The archive certainly works sometimes within 500 years.

Answer (score 10):

After looking at [current gprolog source code](http://sourceforge.net/p/gprolog/code/) where [`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/signal.html) is used:

- src/BipsPl/os_interf_c.c:
  `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`
- src/EnginePl/LINUX_SIGSEGV.c:
  `signal(SIGSEGV, (void (*)()) SIGSEGV_Handler);`
- src/EnginePl/PPC_SIGSEGV.c:
  `signal(SIGSEGV, (void (*)()) SIGSEGV_Handler);`
- src/EnginePl/SOLARIS_SIGSEGV.c:
  `signal(SIGSEGV, (void (*)()) SIGSEGV_Handler);`
- src/EnginePl/stacks_sigsegv.c:
  `signal(SIGSEGV, (void (*)(int)) SIGSEGV_Handler);`
- src/EnginePl/WIN32_all_SIGSEGV.c:
  `signal(SIGSEGV, (void (*)(int)) SIGSEGV_Handler);`
- src/Linedit/ctrl_c.c:
  `signal(sig, Wrapper_Handler);`
- src/Linedit/ctrl_c.c:
  `signal(SIGINT, Wrapper_Handler);`

we can see the only use of signals is:

- to handle `SIGINT` (generated by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) in the REPL
- to handle `SIGSEGV`
- to ignore `SIGPIPE`

So it is not possible, unless you are willing to modify the source code.

Also, I could not find [any mention of signals](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/gprolog.git/log/?qt=grep&q=signal) in the git commit messages.

Comment: Thanks mescalinum... v much appreciated. Shame as I *really* need to interrupt my compiled prolog programs. My next step will be to see if I can blend in some C to catch a signal and trigger a Throw...