# Prolog implementation of nth permutation

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement the nth permutation (`nPr => per(n,L,Out)`) but I keep getting a false.

Here's what I'm trying to do;

```
per(0,_,[]).
per(_,[],[]).
per(R,[H|T1],[H|T]):-
    R1 is R-1,
    per(R1,T1,[H|T]),
    per(R1,T1,T).
```

What am I doing wrong?

*Also is there (an easier) way to implement nth permutation (nPr) using the built in permutation predicate?*

Comment: The n-th permutation, according to the lexicographical order, can be computed [as described in the this article on Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order). Although it probably makes for a more tedious Prolog exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution would be to collect all permutation using `findall/3` or `bagof/3` and then pick the one you need from the list.

If you are using SWI-Prolog, you could use [`offset/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/solution_sequences.pl?show=src#offset/2) from [`library(solution_sequences)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences).

```
once( offset(N, permutation(List, Permutation)) )
```

Or, you could also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364634/count-the-number-of-calls-of-a-clause/11400256#11400256) for a definition of `call_nth/2`, and with it:

```
call_nth(permutation(List, Permutation), N)
```

But of course, if you are serious about this, you should rather find the [n-th permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string) of the indices of your list, and use this to generate the permutation.

Comment: `call_nth(Goal_0, Nth)`

Answer (score 0):

```
per(R1,T1,[H|T]),
per(R1,T1,T).
```

What you're stating here, is that the `R1`-th permutation of `T1` is both equal to `[H|T]` and `T`. That can't possibly be what you mean.

---

Also, per your `per(0,_,[]).`, the zeroth permutation of anything is an empty list. But wouldn't be the zeroth permutation of a list, be the list itself? In other words, `per(0, L, L)`?
*(Or do I misunderstand the numbering of permutations?)*