# In Prolog, can solutions be chosen in random order?

Tags: prolog

If I have the following:

```
a(X) :- X = 1; X = 2; X = 3; X = 4.
```

I can produce solutions in deterministic order:

```
?- a(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4.
```

Is there any method of asking the system to produce solutions in non-deterministic, random order?  For example:

```
?- a(X).
X = 4 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 2.
```

I'm aware that I can find all solutions then select one at random (`findall(X, a(X), Y), random_member(Z, Y).`) but this is too expensive in my case.

---

Possibly clearer example:

```
p(X,Y,Z) :-
  (X = a; X = b; X = c; X = d),   % (D1)
  (Y = a; Y = b; Y = c),          % (D2)
  (Z = a; Z = b; Z = c; Z = d).   % (D3)
```

When deterministic, generating the solution `X = d, Y = c, Z = d` using `?- p(X,Y,Z).` will always go through the 47 previous solutions (`4 * 3 * 4 = 48`).  However, if disjunctions are selected in non-deterministic order, the system might choose `X = d` at D1, `Y = c` at D2, `Z = d` at D3, generating it as the first solution.

This is being used for constrained AI-generated content, so there are many more variables in the real-world use-case.

Comment: Really, it doesn't make much sense to ask for *efficient* randomness.

Comment: @CapelliC With neural networks using [Stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Iterative_method) it is a standard step to randomly shuffle examples in the training set..

Comment: You should expand on what you mean by "too expensive in my case". Do you have too many solutions? Is `random_member/2` somehow too slow? As far as I know, pure Prolog has no way of "shuffling" the order of solutions to non-deterministic predicates.

Comment: How do you expect the first random element is chosen without ever knowing the total number of elements? Also, show an example where findall is not efficient enough!

Comment: @Boris For my real-world case, I have many variables and subgoals, so there are too many solutions to calculate them with findall.

Comment: @false I don't think the total number of solutions is needed beforehand, because I don't need a uniform random selection.  An alternative way to ask my question might be, "is there a way to shuffle disjunctive clauses after invocation?"

Comment: I'd say, look at [`call_nth/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400256/772868).

Comment: @false Does call_nth have to generate all the N solutions?

Comment: This feels like a misguided question. The concept of picking out something at random assumes you have a bag of things to pick from. In the case of say integers, it is enough to define a range, but for things that have to be computed first, well, you would have to compute them first, in _some_ order. If you don't care what the order is, why isn't the default order as good as any other order? PS: If you want useful answers you need to provide more context. Picking a random integer between 1 and 4 is a solved problem.

Comment: "is there a way to shuffle disjunctive clauses after invocation?" Yes, there is: collect them, then shuffle them. Go ahead and read what "shuffling" means.

Comment: @Boris I updated the question with a possibly clearer example.  I'm using it for AI-generated content, so always using the default order would produce boring results, and the solution space is too large to collect all solutions and then pick a random one.

Comment: @2bigpigs: `call_nth(Goal_0, 10)` has to generate all 9 preceding solutions. That's inevitable. If you want to avoid that you will have to change `Goal_0` somehow.

Comment: If you can enumerate the atomic solutions to each subgoal, you can simplify this to generating pseudorandom integers in a range, then map those to the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say in the comments, my impression is that a more important question for your use case is:

> Can solutions be **created** in random order?

(This is because you say that you cannot create them all, and then *choose* a random one.)

To *create* them in a different order, Boris has hinted at a good way: Simply reorder the **disjunctions**!

For example, in the case you show:

```
p(X, Y, Z) :-
  (X = a; X = b; X = c; X = d),   % (D1)
  (Y = a; Y = b; Y = c),          % (D2)
  (Z = a; Z = b; Z = c; Z = d).   % (D3)
```

You could (automatically) create such declaratively equivalent versions of this snippet by exchanging the order if the disjunctions, such as: `(X = c ; X = b ; etc.)`, and each of these snippets may yield the solutions in a different order.

However, it may be easier to first rewrite this to the *equivalent* version:

```
p(X, Y, Z) :-
    member(X, [a,b,c,d]),
    member(Y, [a,b,c]),
    member(Z, [a,b,c,d]).
```

This way, it is easier to *shuffle* the lists and use the randomized lists to generate solutions.

For example, you can change this to:

```
p(X, Y, Z) :-
    random_member(X, [a,b,c,d]),
    random_member(Y, [a,b,c]),
    random_member(Z, [a,b,c,d]).

random_member(X, Ls0) :-
    random_permutation(Ls0, Ls),
    member(X, Ls).
```

Now, you will get answers like:

```
?- p(X, Y, Z).
X = d,
Y = Z, Z = b ;
X = Z, Z = d,
Y = b ;
X = d,
Y = b,
Z = c ;
etc.
```

Note that this way to incorporate randomness to your code is **impure**: There is now implicit global state in your program, and you can no longer easily reproduce results that you need when describing test cases etc. for such programs. A solution preserving **[logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)** has to make this state *explicit*, for example by carrying the random *seed* as one of the arguments, so that each run is completely reproducible.

Note that reordering conjunctions and/or goals like this works only for the **pure** and **monotonic** subset of Prolog, so make sure that you use declarative features like **constraints** to safely exchange goals, and to increase the generality of your code!

Comment: The combination of random_permutation/2 and member/2 is indeed the way to solve my problem.  I see how to adapt my program to that style.  Thank you!

Comment: I see that `random_member/2` is [already defined](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=random_member/2). Is it necessary to redefine it as in your solution? If so, how's your `random_member/2` different?